# Changing a global class from with to without sharing in a managed package

Tags: apex, managed-package, sharing

I have a global class in a managed package and want to change it from with to without sharing in a new release.

Is this possible? Could I do this in a patch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having now done this in real life with our App Exchange managed package, we can confirm that in the context of a managed package:

- You can change a global class from "with sharing" to "without sharing" in a **new** release
- You can change a global class from "with sharing" to "without sharing" in a **patch** release

Answer (score 3):

Like told from Novarg before, you can change the sharing of a global class.
I have already modified the sharing of global classes previously and I have not encountered any problems.
Remember that for the security review, you have to explain the reasons why a class is branded "without sharing".

Comment: Thanks. Did you do this in major releases or patches (or both)? (And, yes, I am well aware of the security review implication!)

Comment: I did it with the major release, didn't try with the patches, but I think you can do it too.

Comment: OK. I'll wait and see if someone can confirm patch compatibility before marking your answer as best... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=packaging_component_attributes.htm&type=5), you can edit API version and the code of the class, but not the name. Given that `with sharing` and `without sharing` is not a part of a name, I would say that you can change it.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the documentation is, as often the case, rather vague which is why I wasn't relying on it directly and hoping someone might have first-hand experience of such a change.

Comment: Regarding the documentation, this says we can edit the code which is true, but it isn't possible to change the signature of a global method, or to remove one, once the package is released. This is what I mean by vague. To find out all the various nuances you either have to be lucky in finding the right documentation, learn from someone else's experience or you have to try it yourself. The latter is a problem with managed packages since you can only find out very late in the SDLC for a change.

Comment: oh, ok. Personally I do not have much experience with managed packages, so I can not give you a first-hand answer to it. But what you can try(I think) is creating a patch and pushing it only to your test org to see if that works.

Comment: that would cover off part of my question, for sure. However, there are differences in the constraints applied at patch and release level too :(